# The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to select DISTINCT StudentID or record but the query says the following error

> The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not
>   comparable

[image]

**Database Relationship**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSELECTALL]


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  DISTINCT(SI.StudentID),SI.Surname,SI.FirstName,SI.MiddleName, SI.StudAddress , 
            SI.BirthDay,SI.Gender, SI.Nationality, SI.BirthPlace,
            SI.TelNum,SI.SchoolWhereGraduated , 
            SI.DatesWhenGraduated, SI.SchoolLastAttended,
            SI.Note,SI.StudImage,
            PI.Father_FirstName,PI.Father_LastName,
            PI.Father_MI,PI.Father_Occupation, 
            PI.Father_TelNUm, PI.Mother_FirstName, PI.Mother_LastName,
            PI.Mother_MI,PI.Mother_Occupation,PI.Mother_TelNum,
            PI.Contact_FirstName,PI.Contact_LastName,PI.Contact_MI,
            PI.Contact_Mobile,PI.Contact_TelNum,PI.Contact_Address,
            SH.SchoolYear,SH.Levels,SH.Section,SH.DateEnrolled

            FROM StudentInformation SI 
            JOIN StudentHistory SH  
                ON SI.StudentID = SH.StudentID
            JOIN ParentInformation PI
                ON PI.ParentID = SI.ParentID


END
```

Comment: am afraid that if studentid is primary key then how come multiple values for same ID ?

Comment: @utility , yes studentid is the primary key, this happens in my `datagridview` when the student has two or more history. Just like this. [Table](http://img8.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/21902/219026986e850f7062aa9d214b412a00526ffd47.jpg)

Comment: Why you do this `DISTINCT(SI.StudentID)` and not this? --> `DISTINCT SI.StudentID,` ???????

Answer (score 2):

Convert your image to `varbinary`. Then you will be able to apply `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting , I  already ALTER my column to varbinary(max). What happens now is when i have two records in my studentHistory table, the name of student also double in my datagridview. Which is not what i want. I only want the student name to display just only once. [Link]( http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/21902/21902532fdfe9c6493b08f459a113a83c63601a8.png)